# Which HTML elements support 'target' attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was selecting all the anchor tags of HTML and checking if it contains target='_blank'. I was under impression that only anchors have targets. But I recently knew that [forms](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp) and [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp) can have targets as well. Can anyone tell me what other elements support this attribute?

Comment: You shouldn't be coming to Stack Overflow for this. Use Google to find the manual!! It's all out there if you look for it.

Comment: W3C can give you a good hand. This question doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically all elements could have the [`[target]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-hyperlink-target), however it's only valid on some.

The following elements may have a valid `[target]` attribute:

- [`<a>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-hyperlink-target)
- [`<area>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-hyperlink-target)
- [`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-base-target)
- [`<form>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-fs-target)

It should also be noted that this list is subject to change. At any point a new or existing element could be modified to make use of the `[target]` attribute given that the use made sense and garnered enough support.